# Hibernate Spring annotation confused

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, annotations

I'm confused in S. H. Annotation. Here is my code
for my first class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="player")
public class Player implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_player")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String pseudo;
}
```

and my second class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="team")
public class Team implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="id_team")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "player")
    private Set<Player> players = new HashSet<Player>();
}
```

it throws the exception:

> mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property:
>   Player.Team in Team.players

i have getters and setters in these class.
how can i make it works? Thank you!

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work! It throws the same Exception.

Comment: i know the class Player doesn't have Team value, and can i fix it without adding that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in `Player` Class:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

private Team team;
```

And replace in `Team` Class:

```
mappedBy = "player" ----> mappedBy = "team"
```